# Multiple afterAdd in Knockoutjs

Tags: foreach, knockout.js

How can I do multiple afterAdds?

```
%tbody{:'data-bind' => "foreach: { data: products, afterAdd: [function1, function2] }"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the function that you bind to afterAdd handle 2 functions:

```
viewModel.myAfterAdd = function(element) {
    if (element.nodeType === 1) {
        viewModel.someFunc();
        viewModel.anotherFunc();
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/XDRx9/

Comment: Github changed the way files get linked. SO it broke the fiddle. The fiddle is now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Define a single `afterAdd` function that will call every other function.

```
viewModel.afterAdd = function(domNode, index, element) {
  // ...

  function1(domNode, index, element);
  function2(domNode, index, element);

  // ...
}
```